# Acessing ordered Class Properties

Tags: javascript

I'm really new to coding and would like some help with this problem: I want to access the objects in my class in some ordered way until I acces the first three.
I thought `this[1]` could mean `this.x` but I found out it can't:

```js
class TargetingSolution{
    constructor(config){
        this.x = config.x
        this.y = config.y
        this.z = config.z
        this.solution = [];
    }

    target (){
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            this.solution.push(this[i])
          }
    }
}

// The following lines of code are not required for the solution, but can be
// used by you to test your solution.
const m = new TargetingSolution({
    x: 10,
    y: 15,
    z: 900
  });
  
  console.log(m.target()); // would print "(10, 15, 900)"
```

So I found this solution down here after trying a lot of different stuff for hours

```js
class TargetingSolution{
    constructor(config){
        this.x = config.x
        this.y = config.y
        this.z = config.z
        this.solution = [];
    }

    target (){
            for (var a in this) {
                if(a === 'x' | a === 'y' | a === 'z'){
                    this.solution.push(this[a])   
                }
                else{
                    break
                }
            }
            return this.solution;
          }         
}

// The following lines of code are not required for the solution, but can be
// used by you to test your solution.
const m = new TargetingSolution({
    x: 10,
    y: 15,
    z: 900
  });
  
  console.log(m.target()); // would print "(10, 15, 900)"
```

But I wonder if there are smarter (but simpler) ways to do that.
Another example of something I tried and I'm not sure whether I got near or not was this:

```js
class TargetingSolution{
    constructor(config){
        this.x = config.x
        this.y = config.y
        this.z = config.z
        this.solution = [];
    }

    target (){
       return config.forEach(element => this.solution.push(element));
    }
}

// The following lines of code are not required for the solution, but can be
// used by you to test your solution.
const m = new TargetingSolution({
    x: 10,
    y: 15,
    z: 900
  });
  
  console.log(m.target()); // would print "(10, 15, 900)"
```

(but it doesn't work because of the `config` in the
`return config.forEach(element => this.solution.push(element));` line

Comment: Hi Thiago, it seems like you try to use config where it is not defined on the line config.forEach(). config is defined in the constructor() function but not in the target() function.

Comment: Yeah, is there anyway for me use the same `config` that's has been defined in the constructor also in the target function?

Comment: I guess you could store it in this way in the constructor this.config = config; and then access it in the target() function as so: this.config.forEach().